# I can't find anything wrong regarding my code, but the script still doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

we have a homework regarding JavaScript. It's not my first work, I've written everything as I should have (far as I know), but my script still won't run. Not even my teacher can find the issue. So I'm left just with you, the Gods of the programming language. Here is my code, the .html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Kvadratická funkce</title>
    <link rel="stylessheet" href="RovStyles.css">
    <script src="RovScript.js"> </script>
    <script>
      function VypKvadr()
        {formkvadr.result.value=Kvadr(formkvadr.x.value,formkvadr.y.value,formkvadr.z.value);}
    </script>
  </head>  

  <body>
    <h2>Kalkulačka kvadratické rovnice</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <form name="formkvadr" action="javascript:VypKvadr()" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="x" placeholder="a">
            <label for="y"> x∧2 +</label>
            <input type="text" name="y" placeholder="b">
            <label for="z"> x +</label>
            <input type="text" name="z" placeholder="c">
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>=0</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Vypočti">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="result">x=</label>
            <input type="text" name="result" readonly>
          </form>
        <td>
      </tr>
    </table>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Here the .css

```
h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 210px;
}

Input[type="text"] {
  
}
```

And here the .js

```
function Kvadr(a,b,c) 
{
var d = (b*b-4*a*c);
  if (isNaN(a)||isNaN(b)||isNaN(c))
    {return "Nelze vypočítat";}
  else if (a==0) 
    {if (b==0)      
      {if (c==0)
        {return "Nekonečně mnoho";}
      
      else if (c!=0)
        {return "Nemá řešení";}
      }
    else if (b!=0) 
      {return ((-1)*c)/b;}
    }
  else 
    {if (d==0)
      {return (-b)/(2*a);}
    else if (d > 0)
      {return ((-b+Math.sqrt(d))/(2*a))+(" , ")+(-b-Math.sqrt(d))/(2*a);}
    else 
      {return "Není reálné řešení";}
    }
}
```

The problem simply is that it won't show anything in the "result" input.
It's probably just something small, something I've just overlooked.

Thank you.

Comment: Your HTML is highly invalid. You cannot open `<form>` in one element and close it `</form>` inside another element. Both opening and closing tag must be inside the same parent element. This is also probably the reason `formkvadr.result` is `undefined`. Instead, wrap your `form` element around the whole `table`.

Comment: And in `Input[type="text"]`, `Input` should be `input`

Comment: You have a few thing going wrong with this code. 
1. you must use selectors to select your inputs (getElementById)
2. you cannot select an input by it's name (so you should use id or class)
3.  you need to defer your js

Comment: @M-Coder For testing code it's okay to work with the automatically created global variables. Also no use for  `defer` since they are only defining a function which won't be called before `DOMContentLoaded`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply place both `<form>` tags outside of the `<table>`, and now this is working.

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Kalkulačka kvadratické rovnice</h2>
        <form name="formkvadr" action="javascript:VypKvadr()" method="get">
            <table>
                 ...
            </table>    
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/zm5sg9tL/1/